# pl/sql insert multiple rows using for loop variable seen as not declared

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've following anonymous block with declared variable:

```
declare
tst number(9) :=0;
begin
for vcnt in 1..1000
loop
tst := vcnt;
insert into samp_tab values(:tst,'a');
end loop;
end;
```

I want to insert into table value of counter into row in every cycle of the loop, by using variable with counter value in insert value. When I execute code, Oracle returns:

```
 Bind Variable "tst" is NOT DECLARED
 Anonymous block completed.
```

How to fix my code?

Comment: Error was described by @Justin Cave. But why not insert rows this way?:  `insert into samp_tab select level, 'a' from dual connect by level<=1000`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to refer to the local variable, don't prefix it with a colon

```
declare
  tst number(9) :=0;
begin
  for vcnt in 1..1000
  loop
    tst := vcnt;
    insert into samp_tab values(tst,'a');
  end loop;
end;
```

This assumes that `samp_tab` is a table with two columns, the first being numeric and the second being a string.  As a good practice, you always want to list the columns you are inserting into explicitly-- that makes your code more self-documenting and it means that you won't create errors later if someone adds new columns to the table later that have default values.